# How can std::unique_ptr have no size overhead?

Tags: c++, c++11

If the size of an empty class can't be 0, what magic is doing std::tuple so the sizeof of unique_ptr is returning 8 in a 64 bit machine?

In unique_ptr the member is defined as:

```
  typedef std::tuple<typename _Pointer::type, _Dp>  __tuple_type;                 
  __tuple_type  _M_t;
```

Where _Dp is the deleter class.

Compiler is gcc version 4.7.1 (Debian 4.7.1-7)

Comment: This may also be implementation-dependent, so you may want to include which compiler you're talking about as well.

Comment: I'm not sure how `std::tuple` relates to `std::unique_ptr` in your question. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Cameron, _M_t is the underlying type on unique_ptr.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The reason is that the `typename _Dp = default_delete<_Tp>` is an empty class and the `tuple` template employs empty base class optimization.

If you instantiate the `unique_ptr` with a non-default delete, you should see the size increase.

Comment: To rephrase a little: when instantiated by itself, a class must have non-zero size, but when instatiated as a base class, zero size is allowed.

Comment: Not really true: I instantiated with my own defined deleter, and got an `unique_ptr` with the size of a pointer. All it needs is the deleter to have a "natural size" of zero.

Answer (score 41):

`unique_ptr` as specified can have zero overhead because the only thing needed to implement it is to modify the process of copying/moving a raw pointer; no additional information is necessary. Therefore `unique_ptr` doesn't need to store anything besides the pointer and can be the same size as a pointer.

As to how your particular implementation, achieves that; Only most derived types need to have a size greater than zero. Empty base classes can take up zero bytes. It's quite common for standard library implementations to take advantage of the so-called 'empty base class' optimization for all kinds of things, from stateless allocators in containers to tuple.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, voted +1  I accepted chill as he has less score and also provided a valid answer.