# Memory footprint of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

Does a `unique_ptr` instance (without a custom deleter) have the same memory footprint as a raw pointer or does an instance store more than just the pointer?

Comment: That is a very implementation-specific question, and as such can differ vastly between different standard libraries. But for a simple check why not use `sizeof` to check and compare to a raw pointer?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Because I thought other people might have the same question in future. Good point. Technically I should have asked: "Is it *possible* to implement `unique_ptr` with the same memory footprint as a raw pointer" as implementations would probably do this if possible.

Comment: the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13460653/2183287

Comment: @AngelinaJolly Good link. Gonna mark this as duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @JoachimPileborg suggested, with GCC 4.8 (x64) this code

```
std::cout << "sizeof(unique_ptr) = " << sizeof(std::unique_ptr<int>) << '\n';
```

produces this output:

> sizeof(unique_ptr) = 8

So, under this implementation, the answer is **yes**.

This is not astonishing: after all, `unique_ptr` doesn't add *features* to *raw pointers* ( e.g. a counter as `shared_ptr` does. In fact, if I print `sizeof(shared_ptr<int>)` the result this time is  `16`). `unique_ptr` takes care for you about of some aspects of pointers management.

By the way, being a `unique_ptr` different from a raw one, the generated code will be different when using one or another. In particular, if a `unique_ptr` goes out of scope in your code, the compiler **will generate code for the destructor** of that particular specialization and it will *use* that code every time a `unique_ptr` of that type will be destroyed (and that is exactly what you want).