# GCC warning for using non fixed-width-integer types

Tags: c++, gcc

In my C++ project, I wanted to use only fixed-width-integers and custom-`typedef`ed integers in all places. But unlike other types, `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long` are not types defined in library. Instead they are keywords built into the language. Hence I can't un-include them if I don't want them. Since they are available, I may accidentally use them.

So, I was looking for a GCC compiler switch, something that disables some keywords for a compilation uint, or something that warns me when I use these non fixed-width types. Is there any flag like that?

Comment: Almost certainly not, but I'll let others post a more definitive answer. Note in particular, that `main` must return `int`. Have you considered `grep`?

Comment: Do you plan on not using the standard library? It heavily uses these types

Comment: OOP - Object-Only-Programming :-)

Comment: If you ever end up on a platform where `int` is not 32 bits, that will be the absolute smallest of your problems.

Comment: @Kevin With the introduction of nodules in C++20, I can compile my source code without it affecting any header files. I just don't want to use them directly in my code.

Comment: @BoP that's true. Maybe I don't want a unprefixed type between all those types with `std::` prefixed to them. It won't look uniform. I either have to add `using namespace std;` (which definitely I'm not) or have to stop using those built-in types.

Comment: @Jeffrey lol. But unlike many other oop, C++ objects aren't costlier than primitive types, isn't it. You just pay for what you use - be it primitive or object.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB: In theory that's true, but in practice the Itanium ABI forces object parameters to be passed on the stack, and never in registers, which makes them very slightly slower than primitives :(

Comment: @MooingDuck Interesting. Why is so? Any related links on the topic?

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58339165/why-can-a-t-be-passed-in-register-but-a-unique-ptrt-cannot Apparntly it only applies to objects with nontrivial destructors or nontrivial copies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a `#pragma` for that, specifically `#pragma GCC poison`.

So you can, for example, do:

`#pragma GCC poison int`

and then any subsequent use of `int` will generate a compiler error.

Caveats:

- do this *after* including the standard headers
- as pointed out in the comments, don't do it in the translation unit containing `main`
- a co-worker might throw coffee over you

Comment: If I am using modules, then I guess it wouldn't matter if I poison at the top of the file. As of now, I don't have a co-worker working in this project. Let me see when that day comes. ;)

Comment: I don't actually know if it would or it wouldn't - you'd have to try it.  Also, be aware that module support is still in its infancy and might not always work as it should.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no GCC compiler switch to remove POD types that are built into the language (or even warn against them).  You will have to use due dilligence here or get creative with a custom solution. Like mentioned in the comments, main must return an int type as well.

Comment: Well main.. yeah. But it's still a project with many files. I can forgive the file with main ;⁠)