# How can std::unique_ptr apply EBO on closure?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

```
#include <memory>

#include <cstdio>

int main(){
    auto x1 = [](int *p){ delete(p); };

    auto ptr = std::unique_ptr<int, decltype(x1)>(new int{1},x1);

    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(ptr)); //  8, unexpected
}
```

the type with lambda have size of 8

Follow up this question:[How std::unique_ptr have no size overhead if using lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58666958/how-stdunique-ptr-have-no-size-overhead-if-using-lambda)

And in my conclusion,EBO(Empty Base Class Optimisation) avoids increasing the object size by inheriting the empty base class

For this purpose, let’s go to Github repository for Microsoft STL implementation of unique_ptr:

and then if we go to line 1229:

https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/memory#L1229

You can see the following helper type:

```
_Compressed_pair<_Dx, pointer> _Mypair;
```

The implementation stores the pointer and the deleter inside a compressed pair.

Throughout the class code you can notice that unique_ptr uses the _Mypair object to reference the data and the deleter. For example in the destructor:

```
~unique_ptr() noexcept {
        if (_Mypair._Myval2) {
            _Mypair._Get_first()(_Mypair._Myval2); // call deleter
        }
    }
```

Let’s have a look at the code:

This time we have to go into the xmemory header:

https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/xmemory#L1487

We have two template specialisations:

The first one:

```
type here// store a pair of values, deriving from empty first
template <class _Ty1, class _Ty2, bool = is_empty_v<_Ty1> && 
                                         !is_final_v<_Ty1>>
class _Compressed_pair final : private _Ty1 {
public:
    _Ty2 _Myval2;
    
    // ... the rest of impl
```

And the second one:

```
// store a pair of values, not deriving from first
template <class _Ty1, class _Ty2>
class _Compressed_pair<_Ty1, _Ty2, false> final { 
public:
    _Ty1 _Myval1;
    _Ty2 _Myval2;
    
    // ... the rest of impl
```

the compressed pair is quite simple, as it considers only if the first type is empty.And I think `std::unique_ptr<int, decltype(x1)>)` use the first one,but before C++20,the [Closure types have no (since C++14) default constructor.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55708180/lambda-closure-type-constructors),So the `_Compressed_pair` in the first one derive the base class without default constructor,how can it create instance `_Compressed_pair<_Dx, pointer> _Mypair;`?

If the constructor of the base class is deleted, then the subclass cannot construct objects either.So how does unique_ptr apply EBO on closure before C++20?

Comment: It doesn't have to be default constructable to have zero size, and your example doesn't actually check default constructability (`sizeof` is an unealuated context). We can copy initialize an empty base with its (noop) copy c'tor, and `_Compressed_pair` defines a c'tor that allows us to do just that.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thanks,I have edited my example,I don't think it should be compiled,because the closure before c++20 don't have ctor,and _Compressed_pair derive from the closure,so why can we constuct instance _Mypair,I am really confused,sorry for my bad english

Comment: Ok, then it seems you believe merely declaring a member `_Compressed_pair<_Dx, pointer> _Mypair;` default initializes it? Because it doesn't, initialization is only in *constructors*.

Comment: Make sure if you're asking about a specific implementation that you ask about that specific implementation.   Microsoft isn't the end-all be-all of C++ by any stretch.

Comment: What is the size of pointers on your machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the constructor of the base class is deleted, then the subclass cannot construct objects either.

**Only** the *default constructor* of the lambda is deleted, but it remains capable of being copy/move constructed.

```cpp
    static_assert(!std::is_default_constructible_v<decltype(x1)>); // different since C++20
    static_assert(std::is_move_constructible_v<decltype(x1)>);
    static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible_v<decltype(x1)>);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cb6eodxfv)

`_Compressed_pair` provides a [constructor](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/xmemory#L1498-L1501) that allows for the copy/move initialization of `Ty_1`.

```cpp
    template <class _Other1, class... _Other2>
    constexpr _Compressed_pair(_One_then_variadic_args_t, _Other1&& _Val1, _Other2&&... _Val2) noexcept(
        conjunction_v<is_nothrow_constructible<_Ty1, _Other1>, is_nothrow_constructible<_Ty2, _Other2...>>)
        : _Ty1(_STD forward<_Other1>(_Val1)), _Myval2(_STD forward<_Other2>(_Val2)...) {}
```

When you construct a std::unique_ptr like this, you provide `x1` as an argument.

```cpp
 auto ptr = std::unique_ptr<int, decltype(x1)>(new int{1},x1);
```

That's how `_Mypair` is constructed.